# Nodejs request module doesn't send Authorization header

Tags: node.js, https, request, http-request

I need to send GET request on https url with "Authorization" header. I try to do this using this code:

```
request.get({
  url: url,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token,
    'abc': 'def'
  }
})
```

On server side I get "abc" header, but there is no Authorization header. Why does it happen?

Comment: Server side is Java, NodeJs ? and you sure your token is not null ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `auth` key? See the details example in the project's [readme](https://github.com/request/request)

`request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});`