# how to send curl Authorization -u of curl in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request, twilio

I don't know how to send the curl -u in node js i try the following code but no luck.

```
request({
            url: "https://preview.twilio.com/HostedNumbers/HostedNumberOrders",
            method: "POST",
            json: true,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": accountSid + authToken
            },
            json: {
                "PhoneNumber": payload.phonenumber, "SmsCapability": true, "IsoCountry": payload.isocountry,
                "AddressSid": address.sid, "Email": payload.email,
                "FriendlyName": payload.friendlyname, "StatusCallbackUrl": "http://example.com/callback",
                "StatusCallbackMethod": "POST",
            },
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            res.json({ 'error': error, 'data': response, 'body': body });
            return true;
        })
```

this is the curl which i want to call.

```
curl -XPOST https://preview.twilio.com/HostedNumbers/HostedNumberOrders \ 
-d "PhoneNumber=+18312011484" \
-d "SmsCapability=true" \
-d "IsoCountry=US" \
-d "AddressSid=ADXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-d "Email=hostedsms@twilio.com" \
-d "FriendlyName=HostedNumberOrder1" \
-d "StatusCallbackUrl=http://example.com/callback" \
-d "StatusCallbackMethod=POST" \
-u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```

Comment: use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944086/nodejs-request-module-doesnt-send-authorization-header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Twilio api

> Twilio supports HTTP Basic and Digest Authentication. This allows you to password protect your TwiML URLs on your web server so that only you and Twilio can access them.

See: [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security)

## Request: http authentication

> Digest authentication is supported, but it only works with sendImmediately set to false; otherwise request will send basic authentication on the initial request, which will probably cause the request to fail.

See: [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication)

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://preview.twilio.com/HostedNumbers/HostedNumberOrders',
  auth: {
    user: username,
    password: password,
    sendImmediately: true
  }
}

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.dir(err)
    return
  }
  console.dir('headers', res.headers)
  console.dir('status code', res.statusCode)
  console.dir(body)
})
```

> Note that you can also specify basic authentication using the URL itself, as detailed in [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). Simply pass the user:password before the host with an @ sign:

```
var username = 'username',
    password = 'password',
    url = 'http://' + username + ':' + password + '@some.server.com';
 
request({url: url}, function (error, response, body) {
   // Do more stuff with 'body' here 
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988737/6836839