# How to use cURL's "-u" argument in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I'm trying to translate a cURL string which includes the line:

```
-u <account>:<token>
```

...but I'm not sure what that maps to in PHP's cURL API.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341870/how-to-send-curl-authorization-u-of-curl-in-node-js), but that's for Node. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: If you stick your whole curl command in this converter: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ does that help? I expect it will come out with something along the lines of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '<account>' . ':' . '<token>');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)