# github search api not giving results when called from request module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl, github-api

I am trying to fetch the results from all repositories of my organisation under a search category. The results are fetched properly when I use the curl command as shown below

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ****" -i https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:<org>+<search_param>
```

But when I try to run it programmatically in nodejs via the request module it is not returning any results.
My code is as shown below

```
const request = require("request");
const options = {
    url:'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:<org>+<search_param>'
    headers: {
        "Autorization": "token ***",
        "User-Agent": "request"
    },
    json:true
}
console.log(options);
request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

The output for the above code is as below

```
body: {"total_count":0,"incomplete_results":false,"items":[]}
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the above code or if I am missing anything.

Comment: try hitting without  `"User-Agent": "request"` and `json:true`

Comment: @mehta-rohan The result was this
statusCode: 403
body: Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.

Comment: tried adding user-agent and json:true. Still total results are 0

Comment: remove just json:true

Comment: works or not..?

Comment: nope same result :(

Comment: working on it..

Comment: I have one thing different i.e. separate my query stirng from url `qs: { q: 'function()' },` and it works.

Comment: are you trying with a private repo? qs also gave me the same result

Comment: ok it is able to search in public and not private

Comment: so is the issue resolved?

Comment: nope the curl command is able to list private repositories but the request module is not getting back all the results.

Comment: I am checking the documentation as well

Comment: I don't have the private repo. can't test it

Comment: but "total_count":0 means your query is unmatched. what do u think

Comment: nope the same query is returning 249 results in curl. Also i tried a basic keyword to test results like `if`. So the output came from the public repository and not from private. Thats how I came to know it is not showing private repository results.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using the axios module instead of request module as the request module does not send the Authorization hader. Got a reference from [Nodejs request module doesn't send Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944086/nodejs-request-module-doesnt-send-authorization-header).

The updated code which works is as follows

```
const axios = require("axios");
const options = {
    method:"get",
    url:'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:<org>+<searchtoken>',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "token ***",
        "User-Agent": "abc"
    }
}
console.log(options);
axios(options).then(function ( response) {
    console.log('statusCode:', response); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    // console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Thanks @mehta-rohan for the help